# Missing rest resource for certain requests in ready api project

Tags: automated-tests, ready-api

I have created a composite project to test rest api using ready api tool and commited to git. Then someone imports that project from git, some api endpoints missed under api section, also some test steps missed under test cases. Here, once I added endpoints under APIs, i renamed services and gave the refering test suite name or meaning full name.

https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/_images/apis/organize/rest-structure.png

I noticed that if I use the same for in both locations, that means test suite name and service, this error happens. How could I solve this problem?.  Because I have already developed this project.

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded everything to git? What do you get from `git status` in your project?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change the names to a different one instead of using the same in both location and do ensure that you SAVE your entire project before committing to GitHub.